# Change from single FrameLayout filling the parent to a dual/split one with top-one wrapping to content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a dual pane, side-by-side layout using FrameLayouts with each effectively filling the height of the screen (barring margins):

[image: dual pane]

The layout of the right `FrameLayout' is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_frame"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details_frag" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="48dp"/>
```

On a certain selection in the left fragment though I want to split the right FrameLayout into two so that I can put different fragments into each whereby the top frame wraps to content while the bottom takes up any remaining space as follows:

[image: Split right pane]

I've been experimenting with adding a new FrameLayout below the existing one and then playing about with weight, height and this is closer to what I want except for the fact that the fragment I want to place in `detaisl_frag_lower` is a `ListFragment` and when there are more entries than fit on the screen then the list ends up being filled beyond the bottom of the screen rather than scrolling within the available area:

```
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details_frag" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="48dp"/>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details_frag_lower" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
```

**Edit** 
BTW I am inflating fragments into each FrameLayout

[image: list extending below screen]
Thanks in advance. Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this all to LinearLayout.  The layout_weight will fill up space for you.  You can show/hide the red pane by finding it with the id, then set pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) (or set View.GONE)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffff00"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/details_frag">
    <!-- Left pane content -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Right pane content -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/details_frag_upper">
            <!-- Initially hidden.  Fill with whatever on left pane click -->
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:id="@+id/details_frag_lower"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <!-- Initially hidden.  Fill with whatever on left pane click -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did consider this and would need FrameLayouts as inflating fragments into them (that doesn't affect your solution). I need to test but would prefer if 'details_frag_upper' had a height `wrap_content`

Comment: You can change the height to wrap_content.  I put in a fixed value for testing.  If I put wrap_content in there, with no content, it would've been 0 ;)